# appendメソッドとconcatメソッドによる計測時間の違い

Tags: java

`.append()`メソッドと`.concat()`メソッドの処理時間について質問です。
以下のようなコードを作成し、`append`と`concat`の計測時間を`currentTimeMillis()`で計測した結果、`append`メソッドは**1ミリ秒**、`concat`メソッドは**0ミリ秒**という結果でした。

---

**currentTimeMillisを使ったコード：**

```
public class Main{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Hello ");
    sb.append("World");
    System.out.println(sb);
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("currentTimeMillisでappend計測時間は" + ( end1 - start1 ) + "ミリ秒");

    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String concatStr = "Hello ";
    concatStr =  concatStr.concat("World");
    System.out.println(concatStr);
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("currentTimeMillisでconcat計測時間は" + ( end2 - start2 ) + "ミリ秒");
  }
}
```

非常に僅かな差だったので、もう少しどのくらい差があるのか確認しようと今度は`nanoTime()`で処理時間を計測しました。`nanoTime`で計測した結果、`append`は**488069ナノ秒**,`concat`は**68340ナノ秒**でした。

---

**nanoTimeを使ったコード：**

```
public class Main{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Hello ");
    sb.append("World");
    System.out.println(sb);
    long end1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("nanoTimeでappend計測時間は" + ( end1 - start1 ) + "ナノ秒");

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    String concatStr = "Hello ";
    concatStr =  concatStr.concat("World");
    System.out.println(concatStr);
    long end2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("nanoTimeでconcat計測時間は" + ( end2 - start2 ) + "ナノ秒");
  }
}
```

---

私が作成したコードで計測した結果、どちらも`append`の処理時間のほうが`concat`より長いと言う結果でしたが、`append`メソッドは新しいオブジェクトを生成せずに連結するのに対し、`concat`は一度`new`をする（新しいオブジェクトを生成する）ので、CPUにより負荷がかかる`concat`メソッドのほうが処時間が長いと思っていたのですが、前述したように`append`の方が1ミリ秒、ナノ秒に関しては桁が違うほど差が出てしまいました。
これは一体なぜでしょうか？私の`StringBuilder`の記述方法が、本来なら使わないCPUに負荷を掛ける書き方をしてしまったということでしょうか？
また、もし私の`StringBuilder`もしくは`concat`メソッドの書き方が間違っていた場合、どのように書き直せばいいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

**追記：**
もう一度図り直してみたところ、`nanoTime()`の`append`メソッドでは**816022ナノ秒**,`concat`メソッドは**34874ナノ秒**と言う結果でした。
先程実行したときに比べて、計測時間が変わっています。そしてまた後にもう一度計測した結果、また違う時間が測定されました。
違う結果が出力されてしまうほど不安定なコード（負荷をかけてしまう）を書いているということでしょうか？それとも、他になにか原因があるのでしょうか？
ご教授いただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 他の方の回答にもありますが、正味の処理のベンチマークを取りたければ、コンストラクタが走る時間を計測区間に含めないような工夫がまずは必要です。また短時間で終わる処理をワンショットで測定するのはバラツキもあるのでおすすめできません。処理の開始終了の実時刻による計測も重要ですが、実際にCPU時間をどれくらい消費したかという比較も必要です。更に一般的なJava処理系ではJITが働くので同じ処理を繰り返し実行すると途中で速度が上がります。Javaでベンチマークを行うためにはかなり複雑な前提作業が必要だということを知っておくと良いと思います。

Comment: 長文ありがとうございます。実行する回数やコンストラクタを含めないこと、加えてCPUの消費量、JITが働くと言う事も理解して比較しなければならないのですね。単なるそれぞれのメソッドに比較では無くJVMやCPUも含めてベンチマークをしなければならないことは完全に知らなかったので、次の際からはこちらの条件を参考にしながら処理時間を計測しようと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

多分、**連結処理自体**は StringBuilder の方が速い（効率的）だと思います。理由は、

> appendメソッドは新しいオブジェクトを生成せずに連結するのに対し、concatは一度newをする（新しいオブジェクトを生成する）

の通り。では、なぜ、サンプルコードがその通りの結果にならなかったかというと、たった 2 つの文字列を連結するだけの処理では、String オブジェクト（`String#concat` の場合）自体の初期化と、String + StringBuilder オブジェクト（`StringBuilder#append` の場合）自体の初期化に要する時間がそのまま所要時間の差になってしまうからです。

次のように、連結処理を 10000 回ループさせてみれば、その差は歴然とします。

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    String out1 = concat();
    long end1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(out1);

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    String out2 = append();
    long end2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(out2);
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("String#concat 計測時間は " + (end1 - start1) + " ナノ秒");
    System.out.println("StringBuilder 計測時間は " + (end2 - start2) + " ナノ秒");
}

private static String concat() {
    String out = "Hello, world!";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        out = out.concat(" Hello, world!");
    }
    return out;
}

private static String append() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello, world!");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        sb.append(" Hello, world!");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

ストレートにオブジェクトの新成回数がスピードの差を生んでいます。

```
String#concat 計測時間は 242394739 ナノ秒
StringBuilder 計測時間は 2665135 ナノ秒
```